# Label Next to Input Field

Tags: forms, webflow

My coworker came up with this idea. Webflow defaults to make forms with label on top of the input field.  There is no easy option to select to put the label next to the input field on the same line.  What my colleague did was use a negative margin for the top of the box model of the input field and add padding, a left margin to the input field. This will align the input field on the same line as the label and next to it.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly cleaner approach is;

- Assign a class to the label, e.g. `Label`
- Give your label a fixed width
- Wrap the label and field in a DIV, assign it a class, e.g. `Field Frame`
- Set the layout of that DIV to flex horizontal.

This gives you a bit more predictability over your label-field layouts, which becomes important as you style narrower breakpoints.

There's a very good chance that at the mobile-portrait breakpoint, you'll want the label to appear above the input field, and flex lets you change that style to vertical easily at any breakpoints you choose.

Of course, another option is to ditch labels entirely, and use placeholder settings instead.